# ASPX PostBack UserControl Lost Value

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, postback

I have a problem; I crate dynamic usercontrol in update panel like this;
Problem is , When Usercontrols created in Page_Load function, I select value from usercontrol's DropDownList  and I click button whis is inside same usercontrol.

when Page Post back, the dropdownlist lost which I selected item. 
BUT When select again my item from Dropdownlist , after I click button and page postback works and my selected item still selected correctly in dropdownlist.

Do you know why dissaper my item from first post back but not second postback ?

code behind is ;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowAgePanel();
    }


private void ShowAgePanel()
    {
        pnlChildAge.Controls.Clear();

    if (ddlChild.SelectedIndex == 0) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(ddlChild.SelectedValue); i++)
    {
        age_usercontrol _control = (age_usercontrol)LoadControl("age_usercontrol.ascx");
        _control.SetInfo("Child " + (i + 1).ToString());
        pnlChildAge.Controls.Add(_control);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found Solution!

Just Add when you create new usercontrol add ID ( ıt must be unique ) like this;

for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(ddlChild.SelectedValue); i++)
{

age_usercontrol _control = (age_usercontrol)LoadControl("age_usercontrol.ascx");

**_control.ID = "AgeUserControl" + i.ToString();**

_control.SetInfo("Child " + (i + 1).ToString()); 
 pnlChildAge.Controls.Add(_control);

}